# Версия сайта для слабовидящих, зачем отключают изображение на этих версиях?

Tags: ui, ux

Разрабатываю версию для слабовидящих, возник вопрос, а зачем настройка отключить изображение.
Хочется получить более развернутый ответ, чем просто что люди плохо видят.
И еще вопрос отключать только фотографические изображение, а нужно ли отключать иконки, которые хорошо видно.

Comment: "а зачем настройка отключить изображение" - уточните в вопросе, где вы такую настройку встретили?

Comment: Ну наверное, потому что экранный диктор бессилен перед картинками.

Answer (score 2):

Версия для слабовидящих должна предусматривать три вещи:

1. Максимальный контраст. Вплоть до использования трех а лучше двух цветов. Я встречал людей, которые не видят красную стрелку (#f00) на белом фоне (#fff) размером с пол экрана.
2. Навигацию клавишами стрелочками. Либо навигацию кнопками громкости (если с мобильного). Тут браузер сделает все за вас. Главное понимать какой контент предыдущий и какой следующий.
3. Чтение контента диктором. И тут очень важный момент - беспроблемное выделение текста по долгому нажатию с мобильного или тройному клику мышью с компьютера.

**UPDATE**

Сначала написал свои мысли, потом мельком решил посмотреть, что пишут другие. Хочется добавить пару мыслей. Во-первых, версию для слабовидящих необходимо делать с помощью CSS или с использованием скриптов, но обязательно без перехода на отдельный URL. В противном случае сайт может попасть под фильтры в поисковых системах. Второй момент - это панели настроек сайта. Ну... я могу сказать, этой диковиной мало кто пользуется. То есть переключатель между разными версиями сайта должен быть (может быть, можно сделать отдельный переключатель для картинок). А так лучше чтобы переключатель включал в себя все опции сразу. Панель настроек для отображения сайта - это слишком. Просматривая статистику использования этой панели, может показаться, что слишком мало слабовидящих людей просматривает сайт. Но, факт в том, что ей будет мало кто пользоваться.

Comment: DID, вы пишете что мало кто ее пользуется, тогда чем они пользуются.
и как это понять 
делать с помощью CSS или с использованием скриптов, но обязательно без перехода на отдельный URL.

Comment: Ну панелями настройки отображения сайта мало кто пользуется. Это я вам точно могу сказать. Например, вы пользуетесь темной версией сайта stackoveflow? Может быть, вы настраивали отображение шрифтов? По поводу второго - это не обязательный пункт в тех случаях, когда не требуется приход посетителей из поисковых систем, а все посетители заходят по ссылке (сохраненной в закладках или введенной с клавиатуры).